# how to resolve AttributeError: module 'graphviz.backend' has no attribute 'ENCODING'

Tags: graphviz, sklearn-pandas

I am not sure why I get an `AttributeError: module 'graphviz.backend' has no attribute 'ENCODING'` when I tried to export regression tree to graphviz. I tried re-installing graphviz and sklearn but it doesn't solve the problem. Appreciate any advice on this.

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-9d9e0becf9b6> in <module>
      3 # graphviz is the drawing tool
      4 from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
----> 5 import graphviz
      6 dot_data = export_graphviz(
      7     model,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\graphviz\__init__.py in <module>
     25 """
     26 
---> 27 from .dot import Graph, Digraph
     28 from .files import Source
     29 from .lang import escape, nohtml

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\graphviz\dot.py in <module>
     30 
     31 from . import backend
---> 32 from . import files
     33 from . import lang
     34 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\graphviz\files.py in <module>
     20 
     21 
---> 22 class Base(object):
     23 
     24     _engine = 'dot'

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\graphviz\files.py in Base()
     26     _format = 'pdf'
     27 
---> 28     _encoding = backend.ENCODING
     29 
     30     @property

AttributeError: module 'graphviz.backend' has no attribute 'ENCODING'
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue when using `pipdeptree`.  It would seem that there was a [very recent change](https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz/commit/8fe0706abcf352ae045661c0705cefe45cbc7e12) to `graphviz`, intended to obfuscate its internals.  Quoting the module author's reply in [issue #149](https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz/issues/149) (a similar issue with `backend.FORMATS`):

> Submodules of graphviz are not part of the public API (cf. https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html). Please stick to the documented interface and use graphviz.FORMATS, see https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#graphviz.FORMATS).

In the short term, you could downgrade your `graphviz` module… it looks like `0.18` was the last tag before the submodules were made opaque.

Moving forward, you may wish to create an issue and/or pull request against the `sklearn-pandas` repository, to replace `graphviz.backend.FORMATS` with `graphviz.FORMATS`, or even just cap its `graphviz` dependency at `0.18`.

Comment: Note that the traceback indicates that the error is in the `graphviz` Python code itself. However I couldn't find this `files.py` in https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz so I'm really confused.

Comment: thanks very much for this lead @macserv! downgrading worked for me too.

Comment: How can I downgrade the graphviz package? I am using anaconda

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and I am very new to Python/conda world, so this might help newbies like me...

I downloaded graphviz 0.19.1 from:
https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/#files

> Source Distribution: graphviz-0.19.1.zip (247.8 kB view hashes)
> [download link](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f6/14/aa3ec10e4ab1524ba69f4742ef9cfa01fd668d0840afe5d5e6f708a95031/graphviz-0.19.1.zip)

and replaced graphviz folder with this version in "C:\Users\Nino\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages" (will be different for you) and rename it so that name is again graphviz.

"C:\Users\Nino\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\graphviz"

Comment: Works for me, grapviz 0.20 also works

Comment: Good to hear. They have updated it. So yes, taking the latest one is best.

Answer (score 2):

I have met same problem! The most voted answer works for me! And paste the code to forceably downgrade the graphviz.

```
pip install --force-reinstall graphviz==0.18
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with `python-graphviz==0.16`. OP did not include a version number, but it looks like the line numbers in the traceback match with v0.16.

Note that the traceback shows the error to be inside the `python-graphviz` package, so it's more likely that it's an issue with a dependency.

With `python-graphviz==0.19` I don't get the import error.

On a side note: Versions shown by `conda list` or `pip list` can be misleading. In case of doubt check the content of the `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue in a different way:

1. Open graphviz file on my PC through following path (Path may differ)
   "C:\Users\Anoop\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\graphviz\backend"
2. Copy the encoding.py file from here
3. Paste this file in the backend
   "C:\Users\Anoop\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\graphviz\backend"
4. Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it seems that the class Base in the "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\graphviz\files.py" takes the 'backend folder' instead of the 'backend.py' on init.

quick solve:
go to "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\graphviz" and rename the 'backend folder' to something else.

PS: since I didn't check the whole code, it may then cause another dependency problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! ver0.2 was trouble some and this error disappear after downgrading it with ver 0.19

Comment: To say thanks to the other users for the answers that helped you, please use comments instead of adding it as a separate answer.

Comment: @ph0enix You miss that this user cannot comment yet ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead  ) and that they did not even taket he [tour] in which they could have learned things like this. If you can link to an existing answer, which this one is saying thanks to, then do so in a flag to bring this inappropriate post to the attention of the moderators.