# AttributeError: module 'graphviz.backend' has no attribute 'ENCODING'

Tags: python-3.x, data-analysis, graphviz

I am trying to import the graphviz to visualize the DecisionTree,

```
import graphviz
```

but after installing the graphviz in Anaconda3, it shows the error:

> AttributeError: module 'graphviz.backend' has no attribute 'ENCODING'.

I don't know how to solve this problem, maybe it is the version of the graphviz or something else?

Comment: Please write question titles that briefly show what you're asking about, not how long and where you searched. I fixed it for you. And please don't upload images of code, always show the code as code formatted text. And show some more code, right now it's only one line that does not show what you're actually doing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to resolve AttributeError: module 'graphviz.backend' has no attribute 'ENCODING'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69989691/how-to-resolve-attributeerror-module-graphviz-backend-has-no-attribute-encod)