# Module 'graphviz.backend' has no attribute 'ENCODING'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, graphviz

I am getting this error with graphviz and nothing is working. I am trying to plot a tree from my xgboost, which uses graphviz.
I tried doing import graphviz and I get the same error. Any idea how to fix this bug?  a previous answer suggested to downgrade graphviz version, but how do I properly do that?

Comment: It is true that Graphviz does not have an encoding attribute, and almost undoubtedly never has.  (all attributes shown here https://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html)  Can you determine what is being fed to Graphviz?

Comment: I am doint a plot_tree from xgboost, so I have no idea what is beign fed into this. But even a simple import graphviz gives the same error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to resolve AttributeError: module 'graphviz.backend' has no attribute 'ENCODING'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69989691/how-to-resolve-attributeerror-module-graphviz-backend-has-no-attribute-encod)

Comment: I tried the solution that suggests to download graphviz .19, but it didnt work. The other solution on downgrading the graphviz package to a previous version I am not sure how to do it